# Запуск скрипта VS Code Python

Tags: python

есть скрипт, который при помощи Python файл открывается, а в VS Code выдаёт ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Евгений\Desktop\учеба\4 семестр\Теория информации\пр7\пр7\huffman.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Евгений\Desktop\учеба\4 семестр\Теория информации\пр7\пр7\huffman.py", line 91, in main
    f = open('sample.txt', encoding='utf-8')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'
```

Сам скрипт:

```
# Реализация алгоритма Хаффмана
from collections import Counter


# Струткра для построения деревьев

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.right = right
        self.left = left
        self.value = value

# Функция получения кодовых последовательностей

def code_in(root, codes=dict(), code=''):
    if root is None:
        return
    if isinstance(root.value, str):
        codes[root.value] = code
        return codes
    code_in(root.left, codes, code + '0')
    code_in(root.right, codes, code + '1')

    return codes

# Функция получения кодированного сообщения
def get(string):
    string_count = Counter(string)

    if len(string_count) <= 1:
        node = Node(None)

        if len(string_count) == 1:
            node.left = Node([key for key in string_count][0])
            node.right = Node(None)

        string_count = {node: 1}

    while len(string_count) != 1:
        node = Node(None)
        spam = string_count.most_common()[:-3:-1]

        if isinstance(spam[0][0], str):
            node.left = Node(spam[0][0])

        else:
            node.left = spam[0][0]

        if isinstance(spam[1][0], str):
            node.right = Node(spam[1][0])

        else:
            node.right = spam[1][0]

        del string_count[spam[0][0]]
        del string_count[spam[1][0]]
        string_count[node] = spam[0][1] + spam[1][1]

    return [key for key in string_count][0]

#Функция шифрования
def coding_huffman(string, codes):
    data = ''

    for symbol in string:
        data += codes[symbol]

    return data

#Функция дешифрования
def decoding_huffman(string, codes):
    data = ''
    i = 0

    while i < len(string):

        for code in codes:

            if string[i:].find(codes[code]) == 0:
                data += code
                i += len(codes[code])

    return data



def main():
    print("Открытие файла")
    f = open('sample.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
    s = f.read() 
    s = s.replace('\n','').replace('ё','е').replace('й','и').lower()
    tree = get(s)
    codes = code_in(tree)
    print(f'Полученные последовательности: {codes}')
    coding_data = coding_huffman(s,codes)
    print(coding_data)
    print("Кодирование завершено успешно")
    decoding_data = decoding_huffman(coding_data,codes)
    if s == decoding_data:
        print(decoding_data)
        print("Строка успешно раскодирована")
    else:
        print("Строка раскодирована не правильно")
    print('Длина исходного сообщения: ' , len(s))
    print ('Длина закодированного сообщения: ', len(coding_data))
    input()  
main()
```

Comment: нет файла 'sample.txt' в директории запуска скрипта (не = где лежит файл). Получите расположение скрипта и укажите файл от этой директории.

Comment: перевести и сам могу,спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае:

```
from pathlib import Path

cur_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
file = cur_dir / "sample.txt"

# и потом в коде
f = open(file, encoding='utf-8')
```

Попробуйте такой вариант.

P.S. Из интереса можно проверить откуда скрипт запущен

```py
# Получить текущую директорию, где запущен скрипт
dr = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
print("Скрипт запущен из ", dr)
```

Comment: cur_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Comment: Поправил cur_dir / "sample.txt" , если будет нужна строка `s = str(file)`

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Выведите в консоль переменную `file` и проверьте соответствует ли она расположению файла `sample.txt`.

Comment: да, присваивается

Comment: А как правильно запустить flake8? Ввожу команду, ничего не выводит? где её можно прописать правильно?

Comment: В директории скрипта в консоли `flake8 myscript.py` по идее должен выдать какую либо инфу. если ничего не выдает значит ошибок не видит.